# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'

Tags: python

I am working on a python sudoku solver but I am not sure why I get this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'`

The error occurs when the solve function calls the `possible` function. Maybe I'm just not thinking clearly as I have been doing this most of the day but here is the code:

```py
import copy

class Sudoku:
    def __init__(self, board, cells):
        self.board = board
        self.cells = cells

    # Creates a board
    def newboard(self):
        values = self.cells.split(" ")
        val_counter = 0
        if len(values) != 81:
            print("Error: Not enough values.")
            exit()
        else:
            for i in range(9):
                for j in range(9):
                    self.board[i][j] = values[val_counter]
                    val_counter += 1

    # Returns row
    def findValidRow(self):
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if int(self.board[i][j]) == 0:
                    return int(i)
        return True

    # Returns col
    def findValidCol(self):
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if int(self.board[i][j]) == 0:
                    return int(j)
        return True

    def possible(self, row, col, val):
        # Check row for value
        for i in range(9):
            if self.board[int(row)][i] == val:
                return False
        # Checks col for value
        for j in range(9):
            if self.board[j][col]:
                return False
        # Checks square for value
        coordX, coordY = 3 * (row // 3), 3 * (col // 3)
        for x in range(coordX, coordX + 3):
            for y in range(coordY, coordY + 3):
                if coordX == row and coordY == col:
                    continue
                if self.board == val:
                    return False
        return True

        # Solves the board

    def solve(self):
        # Checks if cells are all solved
        if self.findValidCol == True:
            print(self.board)
            return True

        # Finds first cell to fill
        row = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidRow)
        col = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidCol)

        for i in range(1, 10):
            if self.possible(row, col, i):
                self.board[row][col] = i
                # Updates values to find new cell to fill
                row = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidRow)
                col = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidCol)

                if self.solve():
                    return True
                # Backtracks
                self.board[row][col] = 0

        return False


        # Get cell values and call solve function
        get_cells = input("Enter cell values seperated by 1 space. Enter 0 for empty cells: ")
        b = Sudoku([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], get_cells)
        b.newboard()
        b.solve()
```

Comment: `copy.deepcopy(self.findValidRow)` is making a copy of the method (`findValidRow` is a method). Did you mean to call that method and pass the return value to `deepcopy`?

Comment: Also in `if self.findValidCol == True:` it probably should have been `if self.findValidCol() == True:` because it is a method

Comment: @Carcigenicate I originally used deepcopy because as soon as the first loop in the solve function starts, the first empty cell will no longer be empty, and I needed to store that cells location for the findValid functions but I changed the structure of solve() so I guess I might not need deepcopy anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
row = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidRow)
col = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidCol)
```

to :

```
row = self.findValidRow()
col = self.findValidCol()
```

You dont need to deep copy `int`, and you need to call the methods not to pass them

Other thing you should pay attention, your methods may return `True` if it wont find, its not best practice, to return different primitives types, if you dont find,  maybe  consider  to return -1

Comment: There is one other part that needs to add parentheses, check my answer for reference

Comment: Yes i only added  in the  functions cal

Answer (score 0):

```py
def solve(self):
        # Checks if cells are all solved
        if self.findValidCol() == True:
            print(self.board)
            return True

        # Finds first cell to fill
        row = self.findValidRow()
        col = self.findValidCol()

        for i in range(1, 10):
            if self.possible(row, col, i):
                self.board[row][col] = i
                # Updates values to find new cell to fill
                row = self.findValidRow()
                col = self.findValidCol()

                if self.solve():
                    return True
                # Backtracks
                self.board[row][col] = 0

        return False
```

Your solve method needs to be modified, add parenthesis into the deep copy part, also the deep copy won't be necessary

and the check if true part (`if self.findValidCol() == True`) because the findValidRow and Col are methods

Answer (score -1):

I assume your mistake is here:

```py
row = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidRow) 
col = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidCol)
```

You are copying the method references. What you really want is to copy the result of the method like

```
row = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidRow()) 
col = copy.deepcopy(self.findValidCol())
```

Edit:
Ignore this answer, copy is unnecessary as int is passed to a function by value

Instead look at the other answer and check your code for more mistakes where you forget to call methods

Comment: Then why are you copying them? It obviously uses the row and col as integers?

Comment: There is one other part that needs to add parentheses, check my answer for reference

Comment: Edited accordingly. Your answer is better

Comment: The previous version of solve() had required them but when I changed it I forgot I don’t need them anymore